# Android server: why it times out incoming connections randomly?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I had to create Android server application that had to listen for incoming connections. It is non-root application and it listens to random high port. The code is trivial and works excellently on desktop Java, it just listens port and implments very simple custom request/response protocol.

I found however that for any reason even Android application is in `accept` method now (i. e. it is supposed to wait for incoming connections), the connection time out often.

I found also that sometimes even system application (ADB server for example) times out incoming connections periodically for no reason. See for example `paping` output:

```
paping -p 5555 192.168.0.105
paping v1.5.5 - Copyright (c) 2011 Mike Lovell

Connecting to 192.168.0.105 on TCP 5555:

Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connection timed out
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=118.02ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=140.02ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=57.01ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=77.51ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=97.01ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=122.02ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=135.52ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=52.01ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=72.51ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=92.51ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=105.51ms protocol=TCP port=5555
Connected to 192.168.0.105: time=5.50ms protocol=TCP port=5555
```

So, it looks like the device times out some incoming data and start to accept after that, later it times out randomly. And ADB is system application, so it is supposed to follow any guidelines and be comparably bugs free.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue and enable Android device to answer for incoming connections fast? Otherwise any application that needs incoming traffic will be buggy and unreliable.

Comment: `the connection time out often.`?? Which connection? The server was listening isnt it? Please clear up.

Comment: Yes, the server is listening, and for any reason some incoming connection time out randomly (can not connect at all) even Java is waiting within `accept` method call.

Comment: You are not blaming a buggy router? Tried other devices?

Comment: I never saw any issues with desktop devices within the same local network for years.

Answer (score 0):

The android OS does turn off the Wifi Radio after a while, if the device is not actively in use. I am not certain what it considers for "in use" though. Maybe that has something to do with it...

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

> Normally the Wi-Fi radio may turn off when the user has not used the device in a while.

In several of my applications I have used the Wifi Lock to keep the radio awake.
Something like this:
**Note** : The application should request the *android.permission.WAKE_LOCK*

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

     @Override
     protected void onResume {
         super.onResume();
         WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
         wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "SYNCVR");
         wifiLock.acquire();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
         wifiLock.release();
     }
}
```

There are a few different options you can specify when creating the wifi lock:
From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

> WIFI_MODE_FULL
>
> In this Wi-Fi lock mode, Wi-Fi will be kept active, and will behave normally, i.e., it will attempt to automatically establish a connection to a remembered access point that is within range, and will do periodic scans if there are remembered access points but none are in range.

-

> WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF
>
> In this Wi-Fi lock mode, Wi-Fi will be kept active as in mode WIFI_MODE_FULL but it operates at high performance with minimum packet loss and low packet latency even when the device screen is off.

-

> WIFI_MODE_SCAN_ONLY
>
> In this Wi-Fi lock mode, Wi-Fi will be kept active, but the only operation that will be supported is initiation of scans, and the subsequent reporting of scan results.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue of new incoming connections requests timeouts. When connection is already established, the connection becomes much more stable when I use Wi-Fi lock. However, it doesn't influence new connections that has to be established.